# Conditionally calculating average time between events by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, conditional-statements, difftime

I am working with a call log data set from a telephone hotline service. There are three call outcomes: Answered, Abandoned & Engaged. I am trying to find out the average time taken by each caller to contact the hotline again if they abandoned the previous call. The time difference can be either seconds, minutes, hours or days but I would like to get all four if possible.

Here is some mock data with the variables I am working with:-

```
library(wakefield)#for generating the Status variable
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)

n_users<-1300
n_rows <- 365000

set.seed(1)
#data<-data.frame()
Date<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 day")
Date<-sample(rep(Date,each=1000),replace = T)

u <- runif(length(Date), 0, 60*60*12) # "noise" to add or subtract from some timepoint
CallDateTime<-as.POSIXlt(u, origin = paste0(Date,"00:00:00"))
CallDateTime

CallOutcome<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Answered", "Abandoned", "Engaged"), n=length(Date))
CallOutcome

data<-data.frame(Date,CallDateTime,CallOutcome)

relative_probs <- rPareto(n = n_users, t = 1, alpha = 0.3, truncation = 500) 
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

data$CallerId <- sample(unique_ids, size = n_rows, prob = relative_probs, replace = TRUE)
data<-data%>%arrange(CallDateTime)

head(data)
```

So to reiterate, if a caller abandons their call (represented by "Abandoned" in the CallOutcome column), I would like to know the average time taken for the caller to make another call to the service, in the four time units I have mentioned. Any pointers on how I can achieve this would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep rows in the data where the current row is `"Abandoned"` and the next row is not `"Abandoned"` for each `ID`. Find difference in time between every 2 rows to get time required for the caller to make another call to service after it was abandoned, take average of each of the duration to get average time.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  #Test the answer on smaller subset
  #slice(1:1000) %>%
  arrange(CallerId, CallDateTime) %>%
  group_by(CallerId) %>%
  filter(CallOutcome == 'Abandoned' & dplyr::lead(CallOutcome) != 'Abandoned' | 
          CallOutcome != 'Abandoned' & dplyr::lag(CallOutcome) == 'Abandoned') %>%
  mutate(group = rep(row_number(), each = 2, length.out = n())) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(avg_sec = difftime(CallDateTime[2], CallDateTime[1], units = 'secs')) %>%
  mutate(avg_sec = as.numeric(mean(avg_sec)), 
         avg_min = avg_sec/60, 
         avg_hour = avg_min/60, 
         avg_day = avg_hour/24) -> result

result
```

Comment: I like this approach, very similar to mine but you filter the rows first. Depending on the size of the data, yours might be faster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your  response. So this solution will get the average time from an "Abandoned" call to the next call, regardless of what the call outcome of the next call is, correct?

Comment: Only if the next call is not Abandoned. If the call order is Abandoned, Abandoned,  Engaged. It will ignore the first Abandoned and will take difference between next Abandoned and Engaged.

Comment: Okay this is good to know. Thank you. If it is not too much trouble, what would I have to change in the ```filter``` section to get the average time from abandoned to the next CallOutcome (regardless of what it is)?

Comment: In that case you change `filter` to `filter(CallOutcome == 'Abandoned' & dplyr::lag(CallOutcome) == 'Abandoned')`

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create the lead variable (basically calculate what is the "next" value by group. Then it's just as easy as using whatever unit you want for `difftime`. A density plot can help you analyze these differences, as shown below.

```
data <-
 data %>% 
 group_by(CallerId) %>% 
  mutate(CallDateTime_Next = lead(CallDateTime)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(
    diff_days = difftime(CallDateTime_Next, CallDateTime, units = 'days'),
    diff_hours = difftime(CallDateTime_Next, CallDateTime, units = 'hours'),
    diff_mins = difftime(CallDateTime_Next, CallDateTime, units = 'mins'),
    diff_secs = difftime(CallDateTime_Next, CallDateTime, units = 'secs')
  )


data %>% 
  filter(CallOutcome == 'Abandoned') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = diff_days))
```